# Асинхронный синхронный код. Как такое возможно

Tags: c++, списки

Имеется программа: строит однонаправленный список, выводит его на экран, затем вставляет новые элементы ДО элементов, которые больше 5.
И в конце концов выводит новый список.
Однако вывод этот работает после добавления некорректно (вывод со 2-го элемента, как будто head не изменился), если вызывать функцию вывода элементов списка в main, однако если же в функции вставки - то все прекрасно работает.
Создается впечатление, что код работает в асинхронном режиме :), хотя и понимаю, что такого не может быть.

Что я упускаю?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct list {
    int data;
    list* next;
};

list* makeNewElement() {
    list* element = new(list);
    cout << "Enter element: " << endl;
    cin >> element->data;
    element->next = NULL;

    return element;
}

list* makeNewList(int N) {
    list *head = makeNewElement();

    list* current = head;

    for(int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        current->next = makeNewElement();
        current = current->next;
    }

    return head;
}

void printList(list* head) {
    list* current = head;

    cout << "PRINTING>>>" << endl;

    while(current) {
        cout << current->data << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

void addBeforeElement(list* head) {
    cout << "Adding!..." << endl;
    list* current;

    if(head->data > 5) {
        list* newElement = makeNewElement();
        newElement->next = head;
        head = newElement;
        current = head->next;
    }
    else {
      current = head;
    }

    while(current->next) {
        if(current->next->data > 5) {
            list* cp = current->next;
            current->next = makeNewElement();
            current->next->next = cp;

            current = current->next;
        }

         current = current->next;
    }

    printList(head);
}

int main() {
    const int N = 3;

    list* head = makeNewList(N);
    printList(head);
    addBeforeElement(head);
    //printList(head);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Объект list созданный в функции, после ее завершения уничтожается. Некорректно возвращать указатель на него в другую область видимости.

Comment: Ааа, не заметил, он указывает на динамическая память выделенную New.. Тогда где её освобождение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`head` меняется внутри `addBeforeElement`.

```
list* addBeforeElement(list* head) {
  ...
  return head;
}

head = addBeforeElement(head);
printList(head);
```